# establishing connection from include file

Tags: php, mysqli, include

The connection file has the following code

```
<?php
return array(
    'connections' => array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'dbname',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'dbpass',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

    ),

);
```

And i am including the above connection file in another page. I can't edit the config.php due to some reasons.

But How can i do the regular mysqli connection with the above array ?

i.e.,

```
<?php
include('../config/config.php');
//$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "wolly");  // need to do the connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM action";
$result = $mysqli->query($query)
```

As in the above the i need the variable  `$mysqli` as the to make the result. But my question is How can i get the values inside the array from config.php ?

Note : I can't make any changes or declare the `$mysqli` in the config.php

Comment: Don't just `return` out of nowhere, define a function and call it.

Comment: Sorry, i can't change anything from the config.php file. I can't do that without changing ?

Comment: If you can't change anything in the config.php file, what is the point of it? How do you use a file that doesn't do anything? You can't grab that information being returning from nowhere.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu returning from an included file is a valid (but not awesome) thing in PHP. It returns that value to the file that called 'include'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
$array = include('../config/config.php');

$mysql_conn = $array['connections']['mysql'];

$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_conn['host'], $mysql_conn['username'],
                     $mysql_conn['password'], $mysql_conn['database']);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM action';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: I am getting   Illegal string offset 'connection error :(

Comment: @ChennaiCityGangsta Please post the exact error message! Also you know that the values aren't the same as in your example for the connection?!

Comment: This is the on i got `<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'connections' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\yy\wrp\public\assets\excel\Ex\05f.inc.php</b>` It repeats for the other too , I mean for mysql, host, connections, username... etc.,

Comment: @ChennaiCityGangsta Do `print_r($array);` if you don't get anything your include doesn't work!

Comment: I can able to get the array info             [mysql] => Array 
                ( 
                    [driver] => mysql 
                    [host] => localhost 
                    [database] => wolly 
                    [username] => root 
                    [password] =>  
                    [charset] => utf8 
                    [collation] => utf8_unicode_ci 
                    [prefix] =>  
                )

Comment: @ChennaiCityGangsta If this is your output then just remove ever `["connections"]`

Comment: @Rizer: It works, actually for a test i returned '0'; in the config.php and now i noted it and removed. Thanks a lot