# php fetching value from array which is included from another page

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
return array(
    'master' => array(
        'details' => array(
            'location'    => 'chennai'
        ),
    ),
);
```

How can i get the value from the above array

I need to assign `$Location = 'chennai'`

But How can i get the value of location from the above array ?

Note : The part of the code is being got from another location i.e., included

Comment: What is this for a fancy 2015 array declaraction: `return array(`?

Comment: I fear that `return` is not declaration. But i want to get data from the that ? Can't I ?

Comment: You can do that, but i never saw it like that, seems to be a bit funny

Comment: @Rizier123 [Laravel 4 uses it for configuration files.](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/config/app.php)

Comment: @Giampy : That was correct, I am dealing with that ,

Comment: @Rizier123 : It might seems to be funny, But can you help me in that. Because that is the configuration file. And i am going to fetch those details from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = include('/path/to/that/file.php');
$location = $array['master']['details']['location'];
```

Comment: `$` signs never hurts!

Comment: Thanks but i am getting **Warning: Illegal string offset 'master' in ... ** error

Comment: `var_dump($array)` see what it says.

Comment: @CiiLearner you sure you didn't returned 0 for testing?

Comment: @Rizer123: Got from it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790294/establishing-connection-from-include-file